# Getting stream posts by fql query with limit returns unexpected results

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Because of October 2013 migration, Graph Api page feed call don't return likes.count field so i had to call another Graph Api call with fql query shown below(if there is ways to get like count per post in one Api call then please help me else read the question further) -

```
select post_id,like_info.like_count from stream where source_id=page_id_here limit 5
```

but it did return only 3 results not 5 as expected ! and this happening mostly when i use access token generated by a application which have October 2013 migration enabled.So how to solve the problem? if i set time limit in the query, then i can't be sure what time limit i specify because my limit setting may be 5,50,100,500 and obviously setting time period is not a proper solution.

Also if i increase limit value say by 50, then for 5 posts(limit value = 55) it may make sense but for desired 100 posts(limit=150) it might not return 100 items and likewise true for more desired posts.
So i am in a puzzle and making my clients late.So please, any suggestions and solutions are very much welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some odd reason, when you specify a subquery (be it a useful or useless one), the desired results are more likely to show up. Example:

```
SELECT post_id,like_info.like_count 
FROM stream 
WHERE post_id IN (SELECT post_id FROM stream WHERE source_id = page_id_here) 
limit 5
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: Now this is funny, and working.I will still keep on adding additional 50 with limit to be sure for getting page/group/profile feed post's like count.if there are  more ways to approach better results tell me please

Comment: Also it seems ok for page feed but for profile feed there must be higher limit value in inner query - "WHERE post_id IN (SELECT post_id FROM stream WHERE source_id = page_id_here limit 20) limit 5" , did not check for group feed yet.

Comment: The Facebook API apparently contains a few bugs. Although I am not sure if this has something to do with the October 2013 migration, it prevents users of the API from getting trustworthy results.